# ¿Por que no se modifica el fichero binario?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo que crear un programa que me modifique la edad de un fichero binario, ademas de otros apartados pero no consigo entender porque no se modifica esta edad, aqui adjunto el codigo, en el ultimo printf de opc1, me sale perfecto pero al volver a listar el fichero este no ha sido modificado. Grcias!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

struct datosCliente
{
char nif[10]; //NIF del cliente
char nombre[20]; //nombre
int edad; //edad
};

struct datosCompra
{
char nif[10]; //NIF del cliente
char nombreProducto[20]; //nombre del producto comprado
float precio; //precio
};

void opc1();
int buscar(struct datosCliente *cliente, char nombre[]);
void listar(struct datosCliente cliente, struct datosCompra compra);
int menu();

int main(){

    int opc;
    struct datosCliente cliente;
    struct datosCompra compra;
    do{
        opc=menu();
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                listar(cliente, compra);
                break;
            case 2:
                opc1();
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
        }
    }while(opc!=4);




    return 0;
}


int menu(){

    int opc;

    printf("1.Listar 2.Modificar 3. Fichero\n");
    scanf("%d", &opc);
    return opc;
}

int buscar(struct datosCliente *cliente, char nombre[]){
    FILE *f;
    long int posicion;
    f=fopen("cliente.bin", "rb");
    if(f==NULL){
        return -2;
    }
    while(fread(cliente, sizeof(struct datosCliente),1,f)){
        printf("HOLA");
        if(strcmp(nombre, cliente->nif)==0){
            printf("HOLA");
            posicion=ftell(f)-sizeof(struct datosCliente);
            fclose(f);
            return posicion;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    return -1;

}

void listar(struct datosCliente cliente, struct datosCompra compra){
    FILE *f, *f2;

    f=fopen("cliente.bin", "rb");
    f2=fopen("compra.bin","rb");
    if(f==NULL || f2==NULL){
        printf("Error de apertura.\n");
        return;
    }
    while(fread(&cliente, sizeof(struct datosCliente),1,f)){
        printf("Nombre: %s, Nif: %s, Edad: %d\n", cliente.nombre,cliente.nif, cliente.edad);
    }
    fclose(f);
    while(fread(&compra, sizeof(struct datosCompra), 1,f2)){
        printf("Nombre: %s, Nif: %s, Precio: %d\n", compra.nombreProducto, compra.nif,compra.precio);
    }
    fclose(f2);
}

void opc1(){
    struct datosCliente cliente;
    FILE *f;
    char nif[10];
    long int posicion;
    int aux;
    int edad;
    printf("Que Nif buscas: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nif);

    posicion=buscar(&cliente, nif);

    if(posicion!=-1 && posicion!=-2){
        f=fopen("cliente.bin", "ab");

        fseek(f, posicion,SEEK_SET);
        aux=cliente.edad;
        printf("Introduce la edad nueva: \n");
        scanf("%d", &edad);
        edad=cliente.edad;
        fwrite(&cliente, sizeof(struct datosCliente), 1, f);
        printf("El cliente %s tenia %d edad y ahora tiene %d", cliente.nombre, aux, cliente.edad);
    }
    else if (posicion==-1) printf("No se ha encontrado la persona inscrita");
    else printf("Error de apertura.\n");
}
```

Comment: Veo que en el método **opc1()** realizas la apertura y escritura del archivo, más nunca haces el cierre del mismo, la función **fclose()** no solo libera los recursos utilizados para la lectura/escritura del archivo sino que adicionalmente hace que la información se escriba en el mismo, tener en cuenta que el hecho de llamar una función de escritura no necesariamente hace que se escriba de una vez la información en el archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte!! Pero ahora se genero otro problema, que se me copia la informacion y se añade al archivo, pero no se modifica la estructura, es decir repite 2 veces la que he cambiado una con la edad vieja y otra con la nueva.

Comment: Debe ser por el modo con el que has realizado la apertura del archivo, el modo **a** (append) es para agregar información al archivo, pero al final del mismo, deberías intentar con **r+**

Comment: Muchissimas gracias! Ya se soluciono!!!

Comment: @GuillermoFuentes Hola, ¿podrías autoresponderte y marcar la respuesta como solución para los usuarios que tengan el mismo problema? Gracias.